# Ruby on rails. Properly validate and rescue code in case of errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, timezone

I have some code here that works fine, but it isn't very safe in case of errors, specificlly `Exception: Timezone::Error::GeoNames` produced from the [Timezone](https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone) gem, where very very occasionally the gem fails to retrieve the timezone from the supplied coordinates.

Users can create gigs, which among other things have a `location` attribute. Location is and address and geocoder converts this address into `latitude` and `longitude`.

The `latitude` and `longitude` are then available after the gig has been saved, so in my controller I have:

```
if @gig.save
     timezone = Timezone.lookup(@gig.latitude, @gig.longitude)
     @gig.update_attributes(timezone: timezone)
  if @gig.timezone
     gigzonetime = @gig.date - @gig.date.in_time_zone(@gig.timezone).utc_offset
     @gig.update_attributes(gigzonetime: gigzonetime)
  else
     gigzonetime = @gig.date
     @gig.update_attributes(gigzonetime: gigzonetime)
  end
       bla bla bla ..................
```

Here the Timezone gem looks up the timezone with the coordinates, after the gig gets saved. This generally works without problems but occasionally throws an error (`Exception: Timezone::Error::GeoNames`), probably when the server temporarily cannot be found.

How can I automatically execute this code after save but have a fallback in case of failure, and set the gigzonetime to UTC (default rails timezone).

`before_validation` in the model doesn't work as it throws  a `Timezone::Error::InvalidZone` error as the `longitude` and `latitude` attributes arn't yet available. Geocoder docs suggest to use `after_validation` so this is why they aren't available.

I feel there is probably a simple solution for this but i'm getting muddled up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't use `before_validation` as long as you have a way of rescuing from the error. Also, is there reason you want to do it after saving? It would make sense to do it before to avoid writing to the DB twice:

```
# `before_validation :set_timezone` should also work
before_save :set_timezone

def set_timezone
  # Do geocoding...
rescue Timezone::Error::GeoNames => e
  self.gigzonetime = "UTC"  # Or whatever
end
```

Comment: I made a mistake. The error isn't the same if using before_validation. The error when using before_validation is Timezone::Error::InvalidZone, as the longitude and latitude attributes aren't available yet. The Geocoder docs recommend after_validation to do it's magic. The rescue code that you have provided looks very much like what I need though.